# Sort() with non-existent values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know that undefined values should be sent to the end of the result, but what about non-existent keys? (Shouldn't be the same?) It seems sort doesn't work in those cases:

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 27
  },{
    name: "Charles",
  },{
    name: "Ellen",
    age: 30
  },{
    name: "Mario",
  },
  {
    name: "Emanuelle",
    age: 18
  }
]

names.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.age > b.age) return 1;

  if (a.age < b.age) return -1;

  return 0;
})

console.log(names) // Sort not working, prints original order
```

Ideally I want to modify the "names" array and not create/reassign more variables.

Comment: names = names.sort() ?

Comment: just fyi - "nonexistent" and undefined is the same in this case.

Comment: @Stefa wrong. .sort() is a mutating operator so there is no need to reassign the result. Even if it wasn't "const" this would be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default sort solution is set to keep the item in its current position --> `return 0`. You could provide another conditional that captures `undefined` and return -1

```js
const
names = [{ name: "John", age: 27 }, { name: "Charles" }, { name: "Ellen", age: 30 }, { name: "Mario" }, { name: "Emanuelle", age: 18 }];

names.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(b.age === undefined) return -1;
  if (a.age > b.age) return 1;
  if (a.age < b.age) return -1;
  return 0;
})

console.log(names) // Sort not working, prints original order
```

Comment: Simple and I just needed to add an extra line. Just a quick question, shouldn't also need to check for `a.age`?

Comment: No, only need to check for the second operand (`b`) so we can place them in the correct order. If you used the first operand as the test (`a`) it would retain the current order. Said differently, the second operand is the one to get shifted before the first in a sort like this - so we need to operate with the second.

Comment: Additionally, as we continue through the sorting, `a` eventually becomes `b`.

Answer (score 0):

So check if the age is defined. If not set it to a large number to force it to the end.

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 27
  },{
    name: "Charles",
  },{
    name: "Ellen",
    age: 30
  },{
    name: "Mario",
  },
  {
    name: "Emanuelle",
    age: 18
  }
]

function getAge (obj) {
  return obj.age === undefined ? Number.MAX_VALUE : obj.age;
}

names.sort(function (a, b) {
  // if (a.age === b.age) {
  //   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  // }
  return getAge(a) - getAge(b);
})

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the property and if not exist, move this objects to bottom. for the rest sort by `age`.

```js
const
    names = [{ name: "John", age: 27 }, { name: "Charles" }, { name: "Ellen", age: 30 }, { name: "Mario" }, { name: "Emanuelle", age: 18 }];
    
names.sort((a, b) =>
    ('age' in b) - ('age' in a) || // sort object without `age` to bottom
    a.age - b.age                  // sort by `age`
);

console.log(names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort not work properly because any number operation with `undefined` are `NaN` I.E: `1 - undefined` = `NaN`.

For this sort, you can use destructuring + defaults, try this:

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 27
  },{
    name: "Charles",
  },{
    name: "Ellen",
    age: 30
  },{
    name: "Mario",
  },
  {
    name: "Emanuelle",
    age: 18
  }
]

names.sort(
  ({ age: agea = Number.MAX_VALUE }, { age: ageb = Number.MAX_VALUE }) =>
    agea - ageb
);

console.log(names)
```